# chart does not display in angular2 component

Tags: canvas, angular, chart.js

I am trying to use chart.js to build charts within an Angular2 component. So far I have not been successful. 
The chart apparently is built but is not shown. The canvas element has null width and height (`<canvas width="0" height="0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></canvas>`).

If I try to do the same with a simpe html page and js script, everything works.

Here is my code. Thanks in advance for any help.

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
      <base href="/">
    <title>Angular 2 Sandbox - Chart component</title>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script src="./lib/chart.js/chart.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyChart} from './myChart.component'
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Here is the App</h1>
    <div style="width:30%">
        <my-chart></my-chart>
    </div>
  `,
    directives: [MyChart]
})
export class AppComponent{ 
}
```

**myChart.component.ts**

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';

declare var Chart: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-chart',
  template: `
    <canvas #canvasElement></canvas>
  `,
})

export class MyChart { 
    @ViewChild('canvasElement') canvasElement;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let lineChartData = this.initializeData();
        var ctx = this.canvasElement.nativeElement.getContext("2d");
        console.log(ctx);
        var thisChart = new Chart(ctx)["Line"](lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });
        console.log(thisChart);
    }

    initializeData() {
        var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
                }
            ]

        } 
        return lineChartData;
    }

}
```

Comment: Setup Plunker, please

Comment: **PROBLEM MAGICALLY SOLVED GETTING CHART FROM CDN.**  Setting up the Plunker I imported chart.js. Plunker made me point to "cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/0.2.0/Chart.js". In my original attempt I was pointing to a local version of chart.min.js (just imported from GitHub). Now it magically works, but I have no idea why is I try to use my local chart.min.js (which works perfectly outside angular2 components) the chart does not show. Thanks in any case

Comment: If you are using SystemJs ( for example ) good approach is to define dependencies trough paths array: 
```paths: {
                    'rxjs/operators/*' : 'assets/js/vendor/rxjs/operator/*.js',
                    'semantic/*' : 'assets/js/vendor/semantic/*.js',
                    'socket.io-client': 'assets/js/vendor/socket.io-1.3.7.js'
                },
``` 
Than with ``` import * as something from 'lib_in_path'``` you can load it in code ( on demand ).

Comment: thanks a lot, Ciao Enrico

Comment: Chart components of PrimeNG can help. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/piechart