# I am creating a chart app in angular 2. I am not getting errors but chart not showing

Tags: angular

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title></title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



    <script src="libs/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   

    <script src="libs/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>


    <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
    <script src='app/app.components.js'></script>
    <script src='app/main.js'></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>
  </head>

  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>

</html>
```

app/main.js

```
(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

app/app.component.js

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<div class="col-md-6">
    <base-chart class="chart"
                [data]="lineChartData"
                [labels]="lineChartLabels"
                [options]="lineChartOptions"
                [series]="lineChartSeries"
                [chartType]="lineChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <base-chart class="chart"
                [data]="pieChartData"
                [labels]="pieChartLabels"
                [chartType]="pieChartType"
                (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></base-chart>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 text-center" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <button (click)="randomizeType()" style="display: inline-block">Toggle</button>
  </div>

      `
    })
    .Class({

      constructor: function() {
  this.lineChartData = [
    [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
    [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  ];
  this.lineChartLabels = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
  this.lineChartSeries = ['Series A', 'Series B', 'Series C'];
  this.lineChartOptions = {
    multiTooltipTemplate: '<%if (datasetLabel){%><%=datasetLabel %>: <%}%><%= value %>'
  };

  this.lineChartLegend = true;
  this.lineChartType = 'pie';
  this.pieChartLabels = ['Download Sales', 'In-Store Sales', 'Mail Sales'];
  this.pieChartData = [300, 500, 100];

  },


  randomizeType:function() {
    this.lineChartType = this.lineChartType === 'Line' ? 'Bar' : 'Line';
    this.pieChartType = this.pieChartType === 'Doughnut' ? 'Pie' : 'Doughnut';
  },
  chartClicked:function($event) {
    console.log($event);
  },

  chartHovered:function($event) {
    console.log($event);
  },

    });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Please help whats wrong in this code.

Google Chrome console shows this message..
"Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode."

Template is in this code also.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: I have not Plunker account. i have also imported Chat.js and Chat.min.js. but still not showing map. only toggle button shows.

Comment: I had problems visualizing charts produced via Chart.js (from chartjs.org) which I solved referencing a 2013 version of the library. Take a look at this hoping it may help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785255/chart-does-not-display-in-angular2-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by adding *ngIf="isDataLoaded" on chart div in html. 
isDataLoaded is the variable which will be true after the response from server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a component, you need to explicitly specify it within the `directives` attribute of your component:

```
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent =
    ng.core.Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `<div class="col-md-6">
        (...)
      `,
      // component class for "base-chart"
      directives: [ BaseChart ] // <-------
    })
    ...
```

Otherwise you component won't be evaluated...

Comment: What do you exactly mean? ;-) Could you update your question with the way you reference the component object and how you set it? Moreover when having a look at the in-memory DOM (in dev tools), can you see something within the `<base-chart>` element? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Is `Chart..js` a third party library? Perhaps it's rather `Chart.js`? I can't any `directives` attribute in `ng.core.Component`...

Comment: its not Chart..js its Chart.js. i correct it. thanks but not working

Comment: please use this code on your browser. then i hope you can solve this better.

Comment: I think that Chart.js doesn't correspond to ng2-charts. It's a library ng2-charts relies on. After having a look at ng2-charts, it seems that you need a module loader to use it (systemjs or commonjs). Do you have one in your application?

Comment: no i don't have. i just want to show chart. is this possible to show charts in simple way?
i have tried ng2-charts but it shows error... "require function in chart.js is undefined"
it means ng2-charts also not a javascript file. i need it in angular 2 javascript

Comment: Yes, your error is normal. I don't know exactly your use case but you could wrap the chart.js code you want to use into a custom Angular2 component.  Which chart do you want to implement (from the doc http://www.chartjs.org/docs/)?

Comment: var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

document.getelementByid not working in angular 2 javascript