# chart.js not displayed in angular2 (rc1)

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js

I have a problem with chart.js and angular2.
Nothing is display when I try to bind a chart to a canvas(inside an angular template).
Outside of angular everything works fine.
My StatisticComponent is included by a router (router-outlet).

component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'statistic',
    templateUrl: 'views/statistic.component.html'
})
class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('canvas') canvasElement;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas');
        //var ctx = this.canvasElement.nativeElement;
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

template:

```
<h2>Statistic</h2>
<canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

when i set a timeout and reference to a global html canvas(not inside a template) then everything works.

i found one similar post:
[chart does not display in angular2 component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34785255/chart-does-not-display-in-angular2-component)

but this didnt helped.
I do not use a systemjs as loader, i use browserify.
Hope someone can help.

//UPDATE

//THIS WORKS
//APPEND NEW ELEMENT

```
class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('container') containerElement;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        this.containerElement.nativeElement.appendChild(canvas);

        var myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

//THIS DOES NOT WORK - WHY?
//USING VIEWCHILD DIRECTLY

```
class ChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('canvas') canvas;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var myChart = new Chart(this.canvas.nativeElement, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try updating your template and wrap your canvas-element inside a div. Don't know the cause to it but the problem seems to appear when the canvas-element is at the root of the template html.

Updated template:

```
<h2>Statistic</h2>
<div>
  <canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking into an existing adaptation to ChartJs with Angular2. For example 
[ng2-charts is a great alternative](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts)  that you might be able to utilize that makes it easier to incorporate into your angular2 app.

Comment: Well i tried ng2-charts and i got the same problem there. Maybe because n2-charts using chart.js. When i try to bind chartjs directly to a ViewChild canvas i get the described result. But when i new create a new canvas element (in javascript) and append it to a viewchild everything works.